# How to make a game on javascript with canvas that makes a sprite appear to be jumping

Tags: javascript, canvas, isometric

I am new to javascript, and am trying to make a game that would hopefully end up isometric (I don't care so much about that, as long as I get an idea of how to). My code is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
<style>
canvas {
    border:1px solid #d3d3d3;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
}
</style>
</head>
<body onload="startGame()">

<script>
var myGamePiece;


function startGame() {
    myGamePiece = new component(30, 30, "blue", 225, 225);
    myGameArea.start();
}

var myGameArea = {
    canvas : document.createElement("canvas"),
    start : function() {
        this.canvas.width = 480;
        this.canvas.height = 270;
        this.context = this.canvas.getContext("2d");
        document.body.insertBefore(this.canvas, document.body.childNodes[0]);
        this.frameNo = 0;
        this.interval = setInterval(updateGameArea, 20);
        window.addEventListener('keydown', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            myGameArea.keys = (myGameArea.keys || []);
            myGameArea.keys[e.keyCode] = (e.type == "keydown");
        })
        window.addEventListener('keyup', function (e) {
            myGameArea.keys[e.keyCode] = (e.type == "keydown");
        })
    },
    stop : function() {
        clearInterval(this.interval);
    },
    clear : function() {
        this.context.clearRect(0, 0, this.canvas.width, this.canvas.height);
    }
}

function component(width, height, color, x, y, type) {

    this.type = type;
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;
    this.speed = 0;
    this.angle = 0;
    this.moveAngle = 0;
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.update = function() {
        ctx = myGameArea.context;
        ctx.save();
        ctx.translate(this.x, this.y);
        ctx.rotate(this.angle);
        ctx.fillStyle = color;
        ctx.fillRect(this.width / -2, this.height / -2, this.width, this.height);
        ctx.restore();
    }
    this.newPos = function() {
        this.angle += this.moveAngle * Math.PI / 180;
        this.x += this.speed * Math.sin(this.angle);
        this.y -= this.speed * Math.cos(this.angle);
    }
}

function updateGameArea() {
    myGameArea.clear();
    myGamePiece.moveAngle = 0;
    myGamePiece.speed = 0;
    if (myGameArea.keys && myGameArea.keys[37]) {myGamePiece.x -=2; }
    if (myGameArea.keys && myGameArea.keys[39]) {myGamePiece.x += 2; }
    if (myGameArea.keys && myGameArea.keys[38]) {myGamePiece.y -= 1; }
    if (myGameArea.keys && myGameArea.keys[40]) {myGamePiece.y += 1; }
    if (myGameArea.keys && myGameArea.keys[32]) {myGamePiece.y -= 3;}
    myGamePiece.newPos();
    myGamePiece.update();
}
</script>

<p></p>

</body>
</html>
```

which I mostly copied and pasted from another website (http://www.w3schools.com/games/tryit.asp?filename=trygame_movement_keyboard). What I want to know is how to make it so that when the player presses space, myGamePiece goes up and down to appear to be jumping; making it move up a certain number of spaces, but then return back to the coordinates it was before.

Answer (score 1):

### Game Physics. JUMPING the basics

**Real world V game world.**

Game jumping is usually done non deterministically, that means you are not sure when or where the play may land. Very much not like real life. In real life once you jump, where and when you land is up to gravity and air friction, unless you can fly the result of jumping is up to the universe.

In the game world this is far from true. The jumper can usually change direction, double jump, do some hang time, or combo accelerated power punch down. All these things can happen at any time depending on the input of the user. Also gravity in the game world does not act like real gravity, sometimes some thing fall faster because they are heavy, some things need a second or to to feel the effect of gravity. The list goes on.

**FALLING**

BUT with all that said the game must still do the important thing that makes falling unlike an elevator ride. When in free fall you accelerate, every instance of time your speed changes, when you jump up you decelerate, when you fall you accelerate. We have our position `y` and our speed `dy` (delta y) to add gravity (g) we add a constant to the speed, when traveling up the screen (dy is < 0) or down the gravity changes the speed in the same direction at the same rate.

So  every frame, add gravity `dy += g` then add our speed to our position y += dy. And that is it a very simple simulation of gravity, which if you measure time in game frames is also a perfect simulation of real gravity (near a big thing like the earth)

Thus the best way to do things like jumping, and the gravity that comes into play is to do it frame by frame.

Lets define what we need to do a jump.

A simple character

```
var c = {
    x : ?, // this character's position
    y : ?,
    dx : ?, // the amount to move per frame The players velocity in x and y
    dy : ?,
    w : ?,  // the character's width and height
    h : ?,
    onGround : false, // a flag to indicate on the ground or not
}
```

And some environment info

```
const GROUND_Y = canvas.height - 10; // where the ground is
const GRAVITY = 1; // in pixels per frame
```

Then every frame we update the character checking if on the ground and if not applying gravity and checking for the ground.

```
c.update = function(){
    if(this.onGround){ // nothing to do but wait

    }else{ // must be in the air
       // Every frame the player accelerates down by the pull of gravity
       // so increase the player y speed
       this.dy += GRAVITY; // apply the gravity to the speed. 

       // now add the y speed to the y position
       this.y += this.dy;

       // Now we must check for the ground which if the player position x,y is for 
       // its center the ground will be half it's height away
       if(this.y + (this.h / 2) > GROUND_Y){ // have we hit the ground
            // yes stop downward motion
            this.dy = 0;
            // the speed may have put the character slightly below the ground
            // so fix the postion so that it is correct
            this.y =  GROUND_Y - this.h /2; // set position to the ground - half its height

            // And set the flag to indicate that the character is on the ground
            this.onGround = true;
      }
       
    }
}
```

So that is gravity taken care of.

**JUMPING**

To jump we apply a force that accelerates us away from the ground. This force is only for an instant, once of the ground we have nothing to push against so we can apply no more force, it is up to gravity to bring us down. As gravity has been sorted in the above function all we need to do is the apply the jumping force.

```
const JUMP_ACCELERATION = GRAVITY * 20; // the bigger this number the higher the jump
```

Now add the function to make the jump

```
c.jump = function(){
     // check if we can jump. That is are we on the ground
     if(this.onGround){
         // flag that we are no longer on the ground and left to the will of gravity
         this.onGround = false;
         // then apply the change in speed. 
         this.dy -= JUMP_ACCELERATION; // subtract jump accel from the speed
                                       // to give a negative speed (up)
      }
}
```

And that is it, the gravity function will take care of everything for you so you must call the `c.update` Function once every frame, the jump function you call only once per jump.

**JUMPING IT DEMO**

Click mouse to jump, a non challenging flappy It.

Taken from an old project this demo shows a very simple jumping character. The object name is `it` and the functions you want to look at are `it.update()`, `it.jump()`, and `it.preJump()`  The code you want is between the comments //Answer code

All the character can do is jump, it can multy jump, and can jump higher if you click and hold the mouse, then release to jump.

```js
/** ImageTools.js begin **/
var imageTools = (function () {
var tools = {
    canvas : function (width, height) {  // create a blank image (canvas)
        var c = document.createElement("canvas");
        c.width = width;
        c.height = height;
        return c;
    },
    createImage : function (width, height) {
        var i = this.canvas(width, height);
        i.ctx = i.getContext("2d");
        return i;
    },
    loadImage : function (url, cb) {
        var i = new Image();
        i.src = url;
        i.addEventListener('load', cb);
        i.addEventListener('error', cb);
        return i;
    },
    image2Canvas : function (img) {
        var i = this.canvas(img.width, img.height);
        i.ctx = i.getContext("2d");
        i.drawImage(i, 0, 0);
        return i;
    },
    drawSpriteLinked : function(image,spriteIndex, x, y, scale, ang, alpha) {
        
        var w,h,spr;
        spr = image.sprites[spriteIndex];
        w = spr.w; h = spr.h;
        ctx.globalAlpha = alpha;
        var xdx = Math.cos(ang) * scale;
        var xdy = Math.sin(ang) * scale;
        ctx.save();
        ctx.transform(xdx, xdy, -xdy, xdx, x, y);
        ctx.drawImage(image, spr.x, spr.y, w, h, -w/2, -h/2, w, h);
        ctx.restore();
    }, 
    drawSprite : function(image,spriteIndex, x, y, scale, ang, alpha) {
        var w,h,spr;
        spr = image.sprites[spriteIndex];
        w = spr.w; h = spr.h;
        ctx.globalAlpha = alpha;
        ctx.setTransform(scale, 0, 0, scale, x, y);
        ctx.rotate(ang);
        ctx.drawImage(image, spr.x, spr.y, w, h, -w/2, -h/2, w, h);
    },        
    drawSpriteSLinked : function(image,spriteIndex, x, y, scale, scaleX, ang, alpha) {
       
        var w,h,spr;
        spr = image.sprites[spriteIndex];
        w = spr.w; h = spr.h;
        ctx.globalAlpha = alpha;
        var xdx = Math.cos(ang) * scale;
        var xdy = Math.sin(ang) * scale;
        ctx.save()
        ctx.transform(xdx * scaleX, xdy * scaleX, -xdy, xdx, x, y);
        ctx.drawImage(image, spr.x, spr.y, w, h, -w/2, -h/2, w, h);
        ctx.restore();
    },
    drawSpriteS : function(image,spriteIndex, x, y, scale, scaleX, ang, alpha) {
        var w,h,spr;
        spr = image.sprites[spriteIndex];
        w = spr.w; h = spr.h;
        ctx.globalAlpha = alpha;
        ctx.setTransform(scale * scaleX, 0, 0, scale, x, y);
        ctx.rotate(ang);
        ctx.drawImage(image, spr.x, spr.y, w, h, -w/2, -h/2, w, h);
    },
    hex2RGBA : function(hex){
        if(typeof hex === "string"){
            var str = "rgba(";
            if(hex.length === 4 || hex.length === 5){
                str += (parseInt(hex.substr(1,1),16) * 16) + ",";
                str += (parseInt(hex.substr(2,1),16) * 16) + ",";
                str += (parseInt(hex.substr(3,1),16) * 16) + ",";
                if(hex.length === 5){
                    str += (parseInt(hex.substr(3,1),16) / 16);
                }else{
                    str += "1";
                }
                return str + ")";
            }
            if(hex.length === 7 || hex.length === 8){
                str += parseInt(hex.substr(1,2),16) + ",";
                str += parseInt(hex.substr(3,2),16) + ",";
                str += parseInt(hex.substr(5,2),16) + ",";
                if(hex.length === 5){
                    str += (parseInt(hex.substr(7,2),16) / 255).toFixed(3);
                }else{
                    str += "1";
                }
                return str + ")";                
            }
            return "rgba(0,0,0,0)";
        }
        
            
    },            
    createGradient : function(ctx, type, x, y, xx, yy, colours){
        var i,g,c;
        var len = colours.length;
        if(type.toLowerCase() === "linear"){
            g = ctx.createLinearGradient(x,y,xx,yy);
        }else{
            g = ctx.createRadialGradient(x,y,xx,x,y,yy);
        }
        for(i = 0; i < len; i++){
            c = colours[i];
            if(typeof c === "string"){
                if(c[0] === " #"){
                    c = this.hex2RGBA(c);
                }
                g.addColorStop(Math.min(1,i / (len -1)),c); // need to clamp top to 1 due to floating point errors causes addColorStop to throw rangeError when number over 1
            }
        }
        return g;
        
    },
};
return tools;
})();

/** ImageTools.js end **/
/** SimpleFullCanvasMouse.js begin **/
const CANVAS_ELEMENT_ID = "canv";
const U = undefined;
var w, h, cw, ch; // short cut vars 
var canvas, ctx, mouse;
var globalTime = 0; 
var globalTimeInt = 0;
var createCanvas, resizeCanvas, setGlobals;
var L = typeof log === "function" ? log : function(d){ console.log(d); }
createCanvas = function () {
var c,cs;
cs = (c = document.createElement("canvas")).style; 
c.id = CANVAS_ELEMENT_ID;    
cs.position = "absolute";
cs.top = cs.left = "0px";
cs.zIndex = 1000;
document.body.appendChild(c); 
return c;
}
var resized = false;
resizeCanvas = function () {
if (canvas === U) { canvas = createCanvas(); }
canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
canvas.height = window.innerHeight; 
resized = true;
ctx = canvas.getContext("2d"); 
if (typeof setGlobals === "function") { setGlobals(); }
}
setGlobals = function(){ 
cw = (w = canvas.width) / 2; ch = (h = canvas.height) / 2; 
if(it !== undefined){
    it = createIt(cw,ch,sprites);
}
}
mouse = (function(){
function preventDefault(e) { e.preventDefault(); }
var mouse = {
    x : 0, y : 0, w : 0, alt : false, shift : false, ctrl : false, buttonRaw : 0,
    over : false,  // mouse is over the element
    bm : [1, 2, 4, 6, 5, 3], // masks for setting and clearing button raw bits;
    mouseEvents : "mousemove,mousedown,mouseup,mouseout,mouseover,mousewheel,DOMMouseScroll".split(",")
};
var m = mouse;
function mouseMove(e) {
    var t = e.type;
    m.x = e.offsetX; m.y = e.offsetY;
    if (m.x === U) { m.x = e.clientX; m.y = e.clientY; }
    m.alt = e.altKey; m.shift = e.shiftKey; m.ctrl = e.ctrlKey;
    if (t === "mousedown") { m.buttonRaw |= m.bm[e.which-1]; }  
    else if (t === "mouseup") { m.buttonRaw &= m.bm[e.which + 2]; }
    else if (t === "mouseout") { m.buttonRaw = 0; m.over = false; }
    else if (t === "mouseover") { m.over = true; }
    else if (t === "mousewheel") { m.w = e.wheelDelta; }
    else if (t === "DOMMouseScroll") { m.w = -e.detail; }
    if (m.callbacks) { m.callbacks.forEach(c => c(e)); }
    e.preventDefault();
}
m.addCallback = function (callback) {
    if (typeof callback === "function") {
        if (m.callbacks === U) { m.callbacks = [callback]; }
        else { m.callbacks.push(callback); }
    } else { throw new TypeError("mouse.addCallback argument must be a function"); }
}
m.start = function (element, blockContextMenu) {
    if (m.element !== U) { m.removeMouse(); }        
    m.element = element === U ? document : element;
    m.blockContextMenu = blockContextMenu === U ? false : blockContextMenu;
    m.mouseEvents.forEach( n => { m.element.addEventListener(n, mouseMove); } );
    if (m.blockContextMenu === true) { m.element.addEventListener("contextmenu", preventDefault, false); }
}
m.remove = function () {
    if (m.element !== U) {
        m.mouseEvents.forEach(n => { m.element.removeEventListener(n, mouseMove); } );
        if (m.contextMenuBlocked === true) { m.element.removeEventListener("contextmenu", preventDefault);}
        m.element = m.callbacks = m.contextMenuBlocked = U;
    }
}
return mouse;
})();
var done = function(){
window.removeEventListener("resize",resizeCanvas)
mouse.remove();
document.body.removeChild(canvas);    
canvas = ctx = mouse = U;
L("All done!")
}

resizeCanvas(); // create and size canvas
resized = false;
mouse.start(canvas,true); // start mouse on canvas and block context menu
window.addEventListener("resize",resizeCanvas); // add resize event
function drawText(text,x,y,size,col){
var f = size + "px Arial";
if(f !== ctx.font){
    ctx.font = f;
} 
ctx.textAlign = "center";
ctx.textBaseline = "middle";
ctx.fillStyle = col;
ctx.fillText(text,x,y);
}
function drawLoad(){
if(!resourcesReady || !canPlay){
    drawText(message,cw,ch * 0.5, FONT_SIZE, MESSAGE_COL);
    if (!canPlay && resourcesReady){
        drawText("Try reloading the page.",cw,ch * 0.5 + FONT_SIZE + 8,Math.floor(FONT_SIZE /2) ,MESSAGE_COL);
    }else{
        
        drawText("Loading resources." ,cw,ch * 0.5 + FONT_SIZE + 8,Math.floor(FONT_SIZE /2) ,MESSAGE_COL);
    }
    
}else{
    if(message !== ""){
        drawText(message,cw,ch * 0.5, FONT_SIZE, MESSAGE_COL);
        
    }
}
}
const FONT = "px Arial"
const FONT_SIZE = Math.max(Math.floor(window.innerHeight/20),24)
ctx.textAlign = "center";
ctx.textBaseline = "middle";
function loaded(e){
if(e.type !== "error"){
    this.sprites = [
        { x : 0, y : 0, w : 74, h : 116, },
        { x : 0, y : 126, w : 100, h : 113, },
        { x : 75, y : 0, w : 29, h : 42, },
        { x : 75, y : 43, w : 17, h : 22, },
        { x : 0, y : 249, w : 42, h : 18, },
        { x : 75, y : 66, w : 17, h : 15, },
        { x : 75, y : 82, w : 17, h : 12, },
        { x : 75, y : 95, w : 16, h : 9, },
        { x : 75, y : 105, w : 7, h : 7, },
        { x : 0, y : 268, w : 11, h : 5, },
    ]
    resourcesReady = true;
    canPlay = true;
    it = createIt(cw,ch,this );
    message = "";
    return;
}
resourcesReady = true;
message = "LOAD FAILED!"

}
var it = null; // it is the character
var resourcesReady = false;
var canPlay = false;
var message = "Please Wait..."
const MESSAGE_COL = "white";
//var sprites = imageTools.loadImage("GreenIt.png",loaded )
var sprites = imageTools.loadImage("https://i.stack.imgur.com/ED6oC.png",loaded )
var background = imageTools.createImage(8,8);
background.ctx.fillStyle = imageTools.createGradient(ctx,"linear",0,0,8,8,["#0AF","#05A"]);
background.ctx.fillRect(0,0,8,8);
var ground = imageTools.createImage(8,32);
ground.ctx.fillStyle = imageTools.createGradient(ctx,"linear",0,0,8,32,["#0A0","#450","#754"]);
ground.ctx.fillRect(0,0,8,32);
ground.ctx.fillStyle = "black";
ground.ctx.fillRect(0,0,8,4);
const GROUND_OFFSET = 32;
const GRAV = 1;
var landed = false;
const MESSAGES = [
"Click mouse button to Jump",
"Click hold ... release to to add power to jump",
"Double click to double jump",
""
];
var messageCount = 0;
var fly = { // something to see
x : 0,
y : 0,
dx : 0,
dy : 0,
wait : 0,
onTheWall : false,
update : function(){
    if(this.wait <= 0){
        this.wait = Math.random() * 200+ 60;
        this.onTheWall = Math.random() < 0.1 ? true : false;
        if(this.onTheWall){
            this.dx = 0;
            this.dy = 0;
        }else{
            this.wait = Math.random() < 0.2 ? 10 : this.wait;
            var x = (Math.random()-0.5) * 200;
            var y = (Math.random()-0.5) * 200;
            this.dx = (x - this.x) / this.wait;
            this.dx = (y - this.y) / this.wait;
            
        }
    }else{
        this.wait -= 1;
        this.x += this.dx;
        this.y += this.dy;
    }
}
};

/*==============================================================================================
// Answer code
==============================================================================================*/
// info to define the character
const IT = {
body : 0,  // sprite indexes
bodyFly : 1,
footDown : 2,
eyeOpen : 3,
foot : 4,
mouthOpen : 5,
eyeShut : 6,
mouthSmirk : 7,
eyeBall : 8,
mouth : 9,  // sprite index end
grav : GRAV, // grav accel
maxJumpPower : 40,
minJump : 10,
jumpPower : 30,  // mutiplys squat amount to give jump power
squatRate : 1,  // how quick the squat is
squatResist : 0.8,  // limits the amount of squat
landingBlinkTime : 30, // how long blink is on landing
blinkTime : 15, // how many frames to close eyes
blinkRate : 60 * 3, // 60 is one second . Time between blinks average
eyePos : {x : 0.13, y : -0.1}, // position as fraction of size
footPos : {x : 0.3, y : 0.5}, // position as fraction of size
lookAtGround : 1, // look ats
lookAtMouse : 2,
lookAtUser : 3,
lookAtFly : 4,
angle: 0,
jumpDy: 0,  // the jump up speed used to rotate It when in air

}
// Function updates the character
const updateIt = function(){
if(this.blink > 0){
    this.blink -= 1; 
}
if(this.blinkTimer > 0){
    this.blinkTimer -= 1;
    if(this.blinkTimer === 0){
        this.blink = IT.blinkTime;
    }
}else{
    // the two randoms create a random number that has a gausian distrabution centered on 0.5
    // this creates a more realistic set of numbers.
    this.blinkTimer = Math.floor(IT.blinkRate * (Math.random() + Math.random())/2 + IT.blinkRate / 2);
    this.lookAt = Math.random() < 0.33 ? IT.lookAtUser : (Math.random() < 0.5 ? IT.lookAtMouse : IT.lookAtFly);
}
if(!this.onGround){
    this.squat = 0;
    //-------------------------------------
    // do gravity
    this.dy += IT.grav;
    this.y += this.dy;
    this.x += this.dx;
    this.x = (this.x + ctx.canvas.width) %  ctx.canvas.width;
    var rotFraction = (this.jumpDy - this.dy) / this.jumpDy;

    this.angle = this.jumpAngle * -rotFraction ; 


    if(this.dy > 13){
        this.lookAt = IT.lookAtGround;
    }
    // check for the ground
    if(this.y + this.tall / 2 > h - GROUND_OFFSET){
        this.y = h - GROUND_OFFSET - this.tall / 2;
        this.blink = Math.floor(IT.landingBlinkTime * (this.dy / 20));
        this.blinkTimer = this.blink + 30;
        this.squat = this.dy;
        this.dy = 0;
        this.onGround = true;
        this.angle = -this.jumpAngle
    }
}else{
    this.squat *= IT.squatResist;
    
}

}
// draw the character
const drawIt = function(){
var bod = IT.body;
var spr = this.img.sprites;
var eye = this.blink > 0 ? IT.eyeShut : IT.eyeOpen;
var foot = IT.foot;
var footBehind = false; // draw feet behind or infront of body

if(!this.onGround){
    if(this.dy >= 0){
        if(this.dy > 2){
            bod = IT.bodyFly;
        }
    }else{
        footBehind = true;
        foot = IT.footDown;
    }
}
var xdx = Math.cos(this.angle);
var xdy = Math.sin(this.angle);
var px = this.x;  // pivot
var py = this.y + 50;
var x = this.x ;
var y = this.y + this.squat;
var t = this.tall;
var f = this.fat;
if(footBehind){
    if(!this.onGround){
        var r = 1 - Math.min(1,-this.dy / 10);
        imageTools.drawSpriteS(this.img,foot,x + f * IT.footPos.x,y - this.squat+  t * IT.footPos.y,1,-1,r,1);
        imageTools.drawSprite(this.img,foot,x - f * IT.footPos.x,y - this.squat +  t * IT.footPos.y,1,r,1);
    }
}
ctx.setTransform(xdx,xdy,-xdy,xdx,px,py);
imageTools.drawSpriteLinked(this.img,bod,x - px,y - py,1,0,1);
if(!footBehind){
    if(this.onGround){
        imageTools.drawSpriteS(this.img,foot,x + f * IT.footPos.x,y - this.squat+  t * IT.footPos.y,1,-1,0,1);
        imageTools.drawSprite(this.img,foot,x - f * IT.footPos.x,y - this.squat +  t * IT.footPos.y,1,0,1);
    }else{
        var r = this.dy / 10;
        imageTools.drawSpriteS(this.img,foot,x + f * IT.footPos.x,y - this.squat+  t * IT.footPos.y,1,-1,r,1);
        imageTools.drawSprite(this.img,foot,x - f * IT.footPos.x,y - this.squat +  t * IT.footPos.y,1,r,1);
    }
}
if(this.blink){
    ctx.setTransform(xdx,xdy,-xdy,xdx,px,py);

    imageTools.drawSpriteLinked(this.img,eye,x + f * IT.eyePos.x - px, y +  t * IT.eyePos.y - py,1,0,1);
    imageTools.drawSpriteSLinked(this.img,eye,x - f * IT.eyePos.x - px, y +  t * IT.eyePos.y - py,1,-1,0,1);
}else{
    ctx.setTransform(xdx,xdy,-xdy,xdx,px,py);
    imageTools.drawSpriteLinked(this.img,eye,x + f * IT.eyePos.x - px, y +  t * IT.eyePos.y - py,1,0,1);
    imageTools.drawSpriteSLinked(this.img,eye,x - f * IT.eyePos.x - px, y +  t * IT.eyePos.y - py,1,-1,0,1);
    var eyeDir = 0;
    var eyeDist = 0;
    if(this.blink === 0){
        if(this.lookAt === IT.lookAtGround){
            eyeDir = Math.PI/2;
            eyeDist = 0.3;
        }else if(this.lookAt === IT.lookAtUser){
            eyeDir = 0;
            eyeDist = 0;
        }else if(this.lookAt === IT.lookAtFly){
            eyeDir = Math.atan2(fly.y, fly.x);
            eyeDist = (Math.hypot(fly.y ,fly.x) /  200) * 0.3;
  
        }else{
            eyeDir = Math.atan2(mouse.y - this.y, mouse.x - this.x);
            eyeDist = (Math.hypot(this.y - mouse.y,this.x - mouse.x) / (Math.min(w,h)/2)) * 0.3;
        
        }
        eyeDist = Math.max(-0.3, Math.min(0.3, eyeDist));
        var ex,ey;
        ex = Math.cos(eyeDir) * spr[IT.eyeOpen].w * eyeDist;
        ey = Math.sin(eyeDir) * spr[IT.eyeOpen].h * eyeDist;
        imageTools.drawSpriteLinked(this.img, IT.eyeBall, x + f * IT.eyePos.x + ex - px, y +  t * IT.eyePos.y + ey-py,1,0,1);
        imageTools.drawSpriteLinked(this.img, IT.eyeBall, x - f * IT.eyePos.x + ex - px, y +  t * IT.eyePos.y + ey-py,1,0,1);
    }
}
}


// While mouse is down squat and prep to jump
const preJump = function(){
this.squat += IT.squatRate;
this.jumpPower += 0.5;
if(this.jumpPower > 30 && this.wiggle === 0) {
   this.wiggle = 1;
}
this.jumpReady = true;
}
// when mouse released apply jump force
const jumpIt = function(){

var power = -IT.jumpPower * Math.min(IT.maxJumpPower,Math.max(IT.minJump,this.jumpPower))/IT.maxJumpPower;
this.dy = Math.sin(this.angle + Math.PI /2) * power;
this.dx = Math.cos(this.angle + Math.PI /2) * power;
if(this.onGround){
    this.jumpDy = this.dy;
    this.jumpAngle = this.angle;
}

this.wiggle = 0;
this.jumpPower = 0;
this.jumpReady = false;    
this.squat = 0;
this.onGround = false;
}

// creates a character
var createIt = function(x,y,img){
return {
    img : img,
    x : x,  // position
    y : y,
    dx : 0, // deltat speed
    dy : 0,
    sqaut : 0, // for landing and pre jump slight squat
    onGround : false,
    jumpPower : 0,
    blink : 0, // blink controls
    blinkTimer : 0,
    lookAt : "ground", /// where to look
    jumpReady : false, // flags if ready to jump
    tall : img.sprites[IT.body].h,   // how tall
    fat : img.sprites[IT.body].w, // how wide
    draw : drawIt, // functions
    update : updateIt,
    jump : jumpIt,
    squatF : preJump,
}
}



function display(){  // put code in here
ctx.setTransform(1,0,0,1,0,0); // reset transform
ctx.globalAlpha = 1;           // reset alpha
ctx.drawImage(background,0,0,w,h)
ctx.drawImage(ground,0,h-GROUND_OFFSET,w,GROUND_OFFSET);
fly.update()
drawLoad();
if(canPlay){
    if(messageCount < MESSAGES.length){
        if(it.onGround && !landed){
            landed = true;
            message = MESSAGES[messageCount];
            messageCount += 1;
        }
    }       
    if(resized) {  // to prevent resize display issue
       resized = false;
       it.y = h - GROUND_OFFSET - it.tall / 2;
    }
        
    if(it.onGround) {
       it.angle = Math.atan2((it.y + 130)-10, it.x- mouse.x) / 3;
       it.angle = it.angle < -1 ? -1 : it.angle > 1 ? 1 : it.angle;
       it.angle = Math.pow(Math.abs(it.angle),0.5) * Math.sign(it.angle);
       it.angle -= Math.PI / 4;
       if(it.wiggle > 0.1) {
          it.angle += Math.sin((it.wiggle * Math.PI) ** 2) * 0.01 * it.wiggle;
          it.wiggle *= 0.95;
       }
    } 
    if(mouse.buttonRaw & 1){
        it.squatF();
    }else{
        if(it.jumpReady){
            it.jump();
            landed = false;
        }
    }


    it.update();
    it.draw();
}
//ctx.clearRect(0,0,w,h);
}
/*==============================================================================================
// Answer End
==============================================================================================*/

function update(timer){ // Main update loop
globalTimeInt = Math.floor(globalTime = timer);
display();  // call demo code

requestAnimationFrame(update);
}
requestAnimationFrame(update);

/** SimpleFullCanvasMouse.js end **/
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you check [this (part 1)](http://www.williammalone.com/articles/create-html5-canvas-javascript-game-character/1/) and [this(part 2)](http://www.williammalone.com/articles/create-html5-canvas-javascript-game-character/2/) tutorial that I have followed.

Your "jump" animation just boils down to creating a `jump` function that sets a max jump height to your object and sets a boolean to `var jumping = true`. As long as your character is "jumping" you increment the y position of your character.

Once you get to your desired height, create a `land` function that does the opposite.

Answer (score 0):

Make a Javascript setinterval to update the height of object after every 20ms.
after every 20s set height = Initial_Height + u*t - (1/2)*g*t^2
use g = 9.8, u = some constant according to your screen.
t = Time passed till now. Which mean, Initially t=0, on first update t=20ms, on second update t=40ms.

Basically, you are simulating real life jumping in gravity.